# show my joomla component to homepage

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

i have default home menu item in main menu which point to a default article.
I want to show my component (i.e com_mywelcomecomponent) into home page of my website.

If try to change the link of menu item to "external link" which point to my component, joomla show me an error

> Save failed with the following error: The home menu item must be a
>   component.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no issue why you cannot make your component as the home component. Login to administrator and then click on main menu. You will find a default menu item which is starred. [image]

Click on that menu and when you go to that menu details just select your component as the default component. 
[image]
When you open your site next time you will find your component on frontpage.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla, Home Menu cannot be an External Link. 
You can still have your component linked to Home page, by selecting the Menu Type which will have your component listed in there and select the appropriate view and Save the Menu.

Answer (score -1):

One easy option would be the Components Anywhere extension: https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/componentsanywhere